# How to fix Mediasoup installation error in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install

While I was installing mediasoup library. I encountered this error, I don't know what caused this or how to fix this. Please help if you have encountered a similar problem.

```
> mediasoup@3.8.4 postinstall C:\Users\shara\OneDrive\Desktop\MediaSoup\server\node_modules\mediasoup
> node npm-scripts.js postinstall

npm-scripts.js [INFO] running task "postinstall"
npm-scripts.js [INFO] executing command: python ./worker/scripts/configure.py --format=msvs -R mediasoup-worker
worker\deps\gyp\pylib\gyp\input.py:1186: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
  if the_dict_key is 'variables' and variable_name in the_dict:
['--format=msvs', '-R', 'mediasoup-worker', 'worker\\mediasoup-worker.gyp', '-I', 'worker\\common.gypi', '--depth=worker', '-Dhost_arch=x64', '-Dtarget_arch=x64', '-Dopenssl_fips=', '-Dmediasoup_asan=false', '-Dnode_byteorder=little']
Warning: Missing input files:
worker\deps\libuv\libuv\common.gypi
worker\deps\libwebrtc\libwebrtc\modules\remote_bitrate_estimator\bwe_defines.h
npm-scripts.js [INFO] executing command: MSBuild ./worker/mediasoup-worker.sln /p:Configuration=Release
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 4.8.4084.0
[Microsoft .NET Framework, version 4.0.30319.42000]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 10/9/2021 11:14:15 AM.
C:\Users\shara\OneDrive\Desktop\MediaSoup\server\node_modules\mediasoup\worker\mediasoup-worker.sln(44): Solution file
error MSB5011: Parent project GUID not found in "mediasoup-worker" project dependency section.

Build FAILED.

  C:\Users\shara\OneDrive\Desktop\MediaSoup\server\node_modules\mediasoup\worker\mediasoup-worker.sln(44): Solution fil
e error MSB5011: Parent project GUID not found in "mediasoup-worker" project dependency section.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.06
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN server@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! mediasoup@3.8.4 postinstall: `node npm-scripts.js postinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mediasoup@3.8.4 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\shara\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-09T05_44_17_989Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your environment is not well set for mediasoup,
make sure you have **python version 3** to start with
and depending on your **os** you need some development requirements as stated on their site [mediasoup version 3 installation guide](https://mediasoup.org/documentation/v3/mediasoup/installation/)

you have any problem, let me know here!

Comment: It's not working! I tried installing it using ```npm i mediasoup@3 --save``` but it didn't work. Please do reply if you have found any answer

Comment: what is your operating system, linux, windows or ios?

Comment: So that we can go together step by step

Comment: I'm using windows. Still couldn't find a better way. I'm trying to find a way around. I'm currently using Zoom SDK for this now. But I'd love to get help from you! So, I can use this in future.